# Who said, "Take that, Jezero!" during the Perseverance landing?

Tags: mars, nasa, perseverance, jpl

During the Perseverance landing broadcast, many of us heard a voice call out, "Take that, Jezero!" Every article I can find simply identifies the speaker as ["a controller"](https://www.washingtonpost.com/lifestyle/kidspost/mars-rover-perseverance-lands-safely-on-the-red-planet/2021/02/18/4704bc20-7232-11eb-85fa-e0ccb3660358_story.html) (or just ["someone"](https://cosmosmagazine.com/space/exploration/perseverance-pays-off/)), and despite how popular the quote has become on social media since then, I still haven't been able to find anything identifying who the speaker was. Does anyone know? Has this legend taken credit for their iconic quote yet?

Comment: Why would anyone say something like that?

Comment: Could it be a mistranscribed *gee zero*? Possibly a reference to something with a technical meaning (ground zero, gee as in gravity,...).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Perhaps, but considering that the landing site was Jezero crater, I think "Jezero" makes more sense in context. I'm also going based on my memories of the audio, not just the transcription in these articles.

Comment: @Giovanni The rover had just touched down in Jezero crater. I guess the controller was just really excited.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @dez.